# Pulling metrics from StarCraft 2 Replays

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a way to pull from a StarCraft 2 replay, every 30 seconds, game play metrics like these :

- Current Unspent Resources
- Current Army Value
- Current Production Facilities
- ...
- etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Sc2Gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/) is a good utility to pull out information like that.  I'm unsure if you can do those specific metrics, but it is fairly flexible and you should be able to create something similar, if not exactly what you want.  It does stuff vs. time quite well and produces all sorts of graphs:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Replay file basically contains only user actions.

So you're require some "emulator" to get such dynamic values like resources count or supply.

I don't know any existing emulator. But I believe that there are some tools that can get this data from RAM but it violates EULA.

Right now I develop [sc2drill](http://sc2drill.com) client to recognize / collect / aggregate data from video stream (it's not prohibited by EULA) but latest version is not published yet. Probably I do it within 1st quarter of 2012. Please support me if you like this idea ^_^

Comment: Like a twitch.tv stream or youtube video?

Comment: Would this be able to capture the Current Unspent Resources?  What is really needed I suspect (to get the metrics I'm looking for) I'll probably need to find some kind of emulator... ugh ;-)

Comment: it's not too hard to create program that reads game memory and aggregate data. This method also can be used while replay watching at x8 so you can get data from replays too.

Comment: There would be no way to write an emulator for this (practically speaking). To convert actions into things like "income" means emulating every nuance of the sc2 game engine, down to the smallest precise detail. And then, you would need to support every version of the engine. And all map features... basically there is just no way to get those kinds of metrics outside of playing through the replay. This is why you can't skip to the middle of a replay without first "playing" through it.